# Explicit curve with unbounded torsion

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I have been trying to experiment with curves. Recently I found a curve (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) with unbounded curvature.

However, I am not able to find one curve with unbounded torsion, for various reasons:

- It has to be in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which makes things more complicated
- Torsion is not as easy to calculate as curvature, I'm aware of the formula $\displaystyle\frac{(\alpha''\times\alpha')\cdot \alpha'''}{k^2_{\alpha}}$

I know the existence of this curves because of the Fundamental Theorem, but I would like to find one explicitly.

Can anyone guide/help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\gamma\colon (0,+\infty) \to \Bbb R^3$ defined by
$$
\gamma(t)
= \left(\frac{1}{t}\cos t^2, \frac{1}{t}\sin t^2, t\right).
$$
Then for all $t >0$,
\begin{align}
\gamma'(t)
&= \left(-2 \sin t^2 -\frac{1}{t^2}\cos t^2, 2\cos t^2 - \frac{1}{t^2}\sin t^2, 1\right) ,\\
\gamma''(t)
&= \left(-4t\cos t^2 + \frac{2}{t} \sin t^2 + \frac{2}{t^3} \cos t^2, -4t\sin t^2 - \frac{2}{t} \cos t^2 + \frac{2}{t^3} \sin t^2, 0\right),\\
\gamma'''(t)
&= \left(8t^2\sin t^2 -\frac{6}{t^2}\sin t^2 -\frac{6}{t^4} \cos t^2, -8t^2\cos t^2 + \frac{6}{t^2}\cos t^2 - \frac{6}{t^4} \sin t^2, 0 \right),
\end{align}
and you can check that, whenever it makes sense, the torsion is
$$
\tau(t)
= \frac{8t^9 - 10 t^5}{20t^8 - 11t^4 + 2}
\sim_{t\to\infty} \frac{2}{5}t,
$$
and thus is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you really much. Is there a physical interpretation of why this curve has unbounded torsion or you just have to come up with it?

Comment: @PedroGarcía I looked for a curve that turns a lot and escapes from its osculating plane. It first tried without the $1/t$ in the two first components, but obtained something bounded in the end. Then I tried with this factor.

Answer (score 0):

If we plot   `Eqn={u Cos[t],u Sin[t], a t}` in 3d we see a linear helicoid whose $u=0$ central line has a constant torsion. The spine twists as can be seen by the rotation of binormal ( not shown).

However, if the third parametric coordinate $z$ red line is kept as any monotonously increasing function then its torsion also increases monotonously as evident in this particular parametrized example:

```
Eq={u Cos[t],u Sin[t],1+Sinh[t]/5}
    ParametricPlot3D[Eq,{u,0,6},{t,0,1.8Pi},Mesh->{3,55},
    PlotStyle->{Yellow},Axes->None,Boxed->False]
```

[image]

Comment: The torsion at $t=0$ is zero, and unbounded for $t>0,~z>0 $.